# Getting latest app version from play store xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

How can I get latest android app version from Google play store? Earlier to used to do so by using below code

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var searchString = "itemprop=\"softwareVersion\">";
    var endString = "</";
    //possible network error if phone gets disconnected
    string jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(PlayStoreUrl);
    var pos = jsonString.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + searchString.Length;
    var endPos = jsonString.IndexOf(endString, pos, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    appStoreversion = Convert.ToDouble(jsonString.Substring(pos, endPos - pos).Trim());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{currentVersion} :: {appStoreversion}");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{appStoreversion > currentVersion}");
    if ((appStoreversion.ToString() != currentVersion.ToString() && (appStoreversion > currentVersion)))
    {
        IsUpdateRequired = true;
    }
}
```

& the code below even throwing exception

```
  var document = 
    Jsoup.Connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.spp.in.spp" + "&hl=en")
    .Timeout(30000)
    .UserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .Referrer("http://www.google.com")
    .Get();
```

Eception:

> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type
>   'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()

But now Play store seems to change few conditions, so existing functionality is broke down. Few similar threads are already available here however those seems to have outdated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574025/5497874

Comment: You need to run it on background thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return a string-based version, at least until Google changes the html page contents again.

```
var version = await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var uri = new Uri($"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={PackageName}&hl=en");
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
    {
      request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html");
      request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
      request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
      using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
      {
            try
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseHTML = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=""htlgb"">)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.{0,1}\d{0,3})(?=<\/span>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(responseHTML);
                return matches.Count > 0 ? matches[0].Value : "Unknown";
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Error";
            }
          }
      }
   }
);
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

Comment: @CGPA6.4 See my regex update, it should match multi-chars xxx.xxx and xxx.xxx.xxx formats now.

Comment: Actually it's more simple solution ?

Comment: Google cahnged the UI and need to change the RegEx: var rx = new Regex(@"""\d+\.\d+\.\d", RegexOptions.Compiled);   This works for now!

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception), this exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193432/pushynetworkexception-thrown-on-pushy-register) wherein it stated that network operations on Android need to be performed off the main UI thread. The easiest way is use a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) to push it onto a thread in the default threadpool.