# Is there any plugin or way to show 'new version of app available' alert when user opens app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin.Android app, I want to show alert to user (when user opens app) that please download latest version. Like other apps. How can I do that?

I have tried few ways but didn't get succeed. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241855/getting-latest-app-version-from-play-store-xamarin). This is quite different from Android. I need it for Xamarin.

I already asked this question but existing functionality broke down due to having some changes in *play store* policies, consequently I am not getting specific string `"itemprop=\"softwareVersion\">"` from `play store` so I asked new question. Thank you

Comment: I always assumed the App would do a web service call to it's home server to see if a new version had been released.

Comment: @RichardHubley - Yeah for sure. But the issue is existing working functionality broke down due to not finding this string `"itemprop=\"softwareVersion\">"`. According to link I have given in question.

Comment: You already asked this question, received an answer, and ACCEPTED the answer.  If that answer was somehow inadequate you need to explain what specific problem you are having with it.

Comment: @ken-white is the same author. he's obviously having a new problem

Comment: @Jason - Existing working functionality broke down due to not finding this string `"itemprop=\"softwareVersion\">"` in `html` coming from _play store_.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I added a new answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463109/4984832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working answer. I have used plugin for that *[Plugin.LatestVersion](https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin)* for Xam.Android to get latest version of app from *Google play store*. below line of code was returning latest app version.

```
var appStoreVersionString = await CrossLatestVersion.Current.GetLatestVersionNumber();
```

Then this is the further implementation

```
private void CompareVersion()
{
    double currentVersion = 0d;
    double appStoreversion = 0d;
    bool IsUpdateRequired = false;
    if (Context.PackageName != null)
    {
        PackageInfo info = Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Context.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
        string currentVersionStrig = info.VersionName;
        currentVersion = Convert.ToDouble(currentVersionStrig);
    }
    try
    {
        if (IsUpdateRequired == false)
        {
            string appStoreVersionString = string.Empty;
            if (CheckNetConnection.IsNetConnected())
            {
                Task.Run(async () => { appStoreVersionString = await CrossLatestVersion.Current.GetLatestVersionNumber();}).Wait();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appStoreVersionString))
                {
                    appStoreversion = Convert.ToDouble(appStoreVersionString);
                    if ((appStoreversion.ToString() != currentVersion.ToString() && (appStoreversion > currentVersion)))
                    {
                        IsUpdateRequired = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (IsUpdateRequired)
        {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                AlertDialog dialog = null;
                var Alertdialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
                Alertdialog.SetTitle("Update Available");
                Alertdialog.SetMessage($"A new version of [" + appStoreversion + "] is available. Please update to version [" + appStoreversion + "] now.");
                Alertdialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (dialog == null)
                    {
                        dialog = Alertdialog.Create();
                    }
                    dialog.Dismiss();
                });
                Alertdialog.SetPositiveButton("Update", (sender, e) =>
                {
                    string appPackage = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        appPackage = Application.Context.PackageName;
                        Utilities.Logout(Activity);
                        var ints = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + appPackage));
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        Application.Context.StartActivity(ints);
                    }
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException)
                    {
                        var apppack = Application.Context.PackageName;
                        Utilities.Logout(Activity);
                        var ints = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + appPackage));
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
                        ints.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        Application.Context.StartActivity(ints);
                    }
                    //this kills the app? 
                    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
                    System.Environment.Exit(1);
                });
                if (dialog == null)
                    dialog = Alertdialog.Create();
                dialog.Show();
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var objLog = new LogService();
        objLog.MobileLog(ex, SISConst.UserName);
    }
}
```